# type 'MappedListIterable<dynamic, Widget>' is not a subtype of type 'Widget'

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm working on a Flutter app, where I need to iterate over a map.

The content of the map looks like this: `({amount: 1, ingredient: Egg}, {amount: 2 ss, ingredient: Havremel})` (It's stored as an array of maps in the DB. Not sure why Dart outputs it like this, instead of a list to begin with).

I'm getting a type error whenever I map over the data. I'm separating the data in a separate function, and calling it from a Column Widget:

```
Column(
  crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
  children: [
    Text(
      'Ingredients',
      style: TextStyle(
        fontSize: 20,
        fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
      ),
    ),
    _getIngredients(recipe['ingredients']),
  ],
),
```

The _getIngredients function. I have tried to type this multiple ways. The error message is commented at the top of each line.

```
Widget _getIngredients(ingredients) {
    
  // type 'MappedListIterable<dynamic, Widget>' is not a subtype of type 'Widget'  
  return ingredients.map<Widget>((i) => Text(i['amount']));

  // type 'MappedListIterable<dynamic, dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'Widget'
  return ingredients.map((i) => Text(i['amount']));

  // type 'List<dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'Widget'
  return ingredients.map((i) => Text(i['amount'])).toList();

  // type 'List<Widget>' is not a subtype of type 'Widget'
  return ingredients.map<Widget>((i) => Text(i['amount'])).toList();    
}
```

Clearly, there is something I don't understand about the type system. I don't understand how I am supposed to figure out the correct types either. I have no problem understanding the regular Dart types, as String, int, List, Map and so forth, however Flutter types threw me off a bit. I usually program in JS or Python, so my experience with types are limited.

Any pointers on how to solve my type problem?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your `_getIngredients` expects a return value of Widget.
In each of you examples you either return a list or a map.

So I think what you want is to return a list of Widget like that:

```
List<Widget> _getIngredients(ingredients) {
  // type 'List<Widget>' is not a subtype of type 'Widget'
  return ingredients.map<Widget>((i) => Text(i['amount'])).toList();    
}
```

And here something like that:

```
Column(
  crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
  children: [
    Text(
      'Ingredients',
      style: TextStyle(
        fontSize: 20,
        fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
      ),
    ),
    ..._getIngredients(recipe['ingredients']), // the ... operator adds to array
  ],
),
```

Comment: Hi Mike. Thanks, your suggestions works like a charm. I understand what you mean by changing the return type from a Widget to a list of Widget. I didn't understand the ... operator, so thats something I need to look further into.

Comment: It's called the spread operator in dart, here is a quick link to a simple but good explanation:
[spread operator](https://www.woolha.com/tutorials/dart-using-triple-dot-spread-operator-examples#:~:text=Since%20version%202.3%2C%20Dart%20adds,List%20%2C%20Set%20%2C%20and%20Map%20.)